# How to keep two separate categories under the same list, but keep other categories separated per se?

Tags: reactjs, redux

as the question says, how do I filter out and keep two categories in the same list, but the "third" category is in a separate section in React/redux?

My component:

```
    {
      categoryGrouping.map((category, i) =>
          this.props[category].length > 0
              ? <Accordion title={`${trans(`HEADER_CATEGORY`)} - ${trans(`CATEGORY_${category}`)}`}
                           description={trans(`HEADER_TEXT_${category}`)}
                           expanded={category === Category.TSHIRTS}
                           key={i}
                >
                <SelectionList>
                  {
                    this.props[category].map((item, j) => <li key={j}><ListItem item={item}/></li>)
                  }
                </SelectionList>
              </Accordion>
              : null
      )
    }
```

In my container:

```
const predicateFunc = category => item => item.category === category;
const sorter = (a, b) => new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime();

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const list = (state.list.list || []);
  return {
    loaded: !!state.list.list,
    [Category.UNDERWEAR]: list.filter(predicateFunc(Category.UNDERWEAR)).sort(sorter),
    [Category.TSHIRTS]: list.filter(predicateFunc(Category.TSHIRTS)).sort(sorter),
    [Category.JEANS]: list.filter(predicateFunc(Category.JEANS)).sort(sorter),
    [Category.SWEATPANTS]: list.filter(predicateFunc(Category.SWEATPANTS)).sort(sorter),
    error: state.list.error
  };
};
```

Lets say I want 'JEANS' and 'SWEATPANTS' in the same list (but they are still two categories), but separate 'T-SHIRTS' and 'UNDERWEAR'.

How I want it:

- T-SHIRTS - Category 1
- UNDERWEAR - Category 2
- JEANS & SWEATPANTS - Category 3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group categories by schema:

```
const sorter = (a, b) => new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime();

const groupCategories = ({ schema, list }) =>
  Object.keys(schema).reduce(
    (acc, category) =>
      Object.assign(acc, {
        [category]: list
          .filter(item => schema[category].indexOf(item.category) > -1)
          .sort(sorter),
      }),
    {},
  );

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const list = state.list.list || [];
  return {
    loaded: !!state.list.list,
    ...groupCategories({
      schema: {
        Category1: [Category.TSHIRTS],
        Category2: [Category.UNDERWEAR],
        Category3: [Category.JEANS, Category.SWEATPANTS],
      },
      list,
    }),
    error: state.list.error,
  };
};
```

Comment: Your answer was even better! It's almost identical what I did (made it a bit different). But I did include Category.JEANS and SWEATPANTS into one array/list as you did which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a reducer / state for the categories:

```
// categories = [['T-SHIRTS'], ['UNDERWEAR'], ['JEANS', 'SWEATPANTS']]
const mapStateToProps = ({categories, list}) => (
  categories.map(subCategories =>
    list.filter(item => subCategories.indexOf(item.category) > -1)) 
)
```

Each category has an array of sub-categories and each item has a category field.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!